# Sort on specific date column

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I have the following AdGridReact

```
      <AgGridReact
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        rowData={pipelineData}
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
      />
```

My columnDefs

```
  const columnDefs = [
    ...
    ...
    {
      headerName: 'My Date',
      field: 'myDate',
      unSortIcon: true,
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      resizable: true,
      suppressMenu: false,
      wrapText: true,
      autoHeight: true,
    }
  ];
```

The date format is "MM/DD/YYYY"

I'm trying to have the default sorting on the myDate column in ascending order.

I have tried multiple ways of achieving this, but none of them have worked.

One of the ways I tried is by using the setSortModel method

```
  const onGridReady = (params: any) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

    const sort = [
      {
        colId: "myDate",
        sort: "asc",
      },
    ];

    params.api.setSortModel(sort);
  };
```

But I get the following error: "params.api.setSortModel is not a function"

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by date, this is the way

```
gridOptions.columnApi.applyColumnState({
  state: [{ colId: 'date', sort: 'asc' }],
  defaultState: { sort: null },
});
```

And do not forget to add a comparator for your date column otherwise it would be regarded as a string

```
{ 
  field: 'myDate',
  comparator: dateComparator
},
```

```
function dateComparator(date1, date2) {
  const date1Number = monthToComparableNumber(date1);
  const date2Number = monthToComparableNumber(date2);

  if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date1Number === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (date2Number === null) {
    return 1;
  }

  return date1Number - date2Number;
}

function monthToComparableNumber(date) {
  if (date === undefined || date === null || date.length !== 10) {
    return null;
  }

  const yearNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(6, 10));
  const monthNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5));
  const dayNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));

  return yearNumber * 10000 + monthNumber * 100 + dayNumber;
}
```

Here's a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hn4Wg7ehOKXt7qpg?preview (Click on 'Date Ascending' button to see it in action)

Further reading: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-sorting/#sorting-api

Comment: Works, thank you. I did have to move the monthNumber and dayNumber due to my date format 
`
    const dayNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5));
    const monthNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
`